# how to change order of archive loop in wordpress 3.0+

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to change the order of a particular archive (custom type/taxonomy) to order by title rather that chronological. I've looked in archive.php and loop.php. How do i pass parameters to the default loop?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `posts_orderby_request` filter. You can check to see if the request is for your custom type, then return a different `ORDER BY` string. Look in `wp-includes/query.php` on line 2583.